# extracting data from JSON object with python

Tags: python, json, extract

I am trying to get data into SAMPLES and LABELS variables from JSON objects which looks like this.

```
{
"samples": [
    [
        28,
        25,
        95
    ],
    [
        21,
        13,
        70
    ],
    [
        13,
        21,
        70
    ]
],
"labels": [
    1,
    2,
    3
  ]
 }
```

the code I am using

```
with open(data, 'r') as d:
complete_data = json.load(d)
for a in complete_data:
    samples = a['samples']
    lables = a['lables']
```

but its says

**samples = a['samples']**

**TypeError: string indices must be integers**

Comment: remove the for-loop - use `samples = complete_data['samples']`, etc

Comment: You trying to use string representation of a dictionary. You should convert it yo dictionary first. Use ast.literal_eval to convert dictionary

Comment: @ikibir, I searched about ast.literal_eval, it says it is used to evaluate the input, to check if it is valid or not. 
can you please guide me more about it?

Comment: @Abdullah on which line does that error occur?

Comment: @EdWard, your solution worked, I took the variables out of **with** block and it worked. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get data from `'samples'` and `'labels'` You don't need to use loop. Try this:

```
import json

with open('data.json', 'r') as d:
    complete_data = json.load(d)

samples = complete_data['samples']
labels = complete_data['labels']

print(samples)
print(labels)
```

Output:

```
[[28, 25, 95], [21, 13, 70], [13, 21, 70]]
[1, 2, 3]
```